# Extracted text comes out as a single line

Tags: python, text-files, extract

I'm wanting to extract ALL text between points A and B which repeats itself X amount of times throughout the text document and looks like:

```
A
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
.
.
.
B
```

Using the code:

```
 results = [] 
 results = False
 for line in lines:
     line = line[1:-1]
     if "B" in line:
         results = False
     elif results == True:
         orbitals.append(line)
     elif "A" in line:
         results = True
```

I am able to extract the desired text but it outputs as a single linear line/row of text ie. A Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 4 B with each time it is repeated in the text also on the same line. Ideally I want it to output exactly how it is presented in the textfile that I am extracting it from (and if possible in columns next to each other in order for each time it is repeated through the text).

Comment: Your requirements seem to be contradictory. How can you have the output being "exactly how it is presented in the textfile" and "in columns next to each other"?

Comment: FWIW, columns are certainly doable, but it's a bit fiddly, since you have to save the data so you can build a 2D grid, making sure everything is aligned correctly. There are modules that can help with that task.

Comment: Add an example of what you want to achieve into your question.

Answer (score 0):

To output the results on separate lines, just do `print('\n'.join(orbitals))`

Not clear what you mean by `if possible in columns next to each other in order for each time it is repeated through the text`

Answer (score -1):

for obtaining the texts as in the text document you can use a loop.

for text in orbitals:
   print text